# I am looking for an assembler that could run in a 64 bit OS as well as in a 32 bit OS

Tags: assembly

I am used to program assembly codes in a86. I am looking for an assembler that could run in a 64 bit OS as well as in a 32 bit OS. Do you know any?

Comment: What do you mean with "run in"?

Answer (score 1):

perhaps [YASM](http://yasm.tortall.net/)? It is small NASM style assembler which supports both x86 and amd64 architectures. From the homepage:

> Yasm currently supports the x86 and AMD64 instruction sets, accepts
>   NASM and GAS assembler syntaxes, outputs binary, ELF32, ELF64, 32 and
>   64-bit Mach-O, RDOFF2, COFF, Win32, and Win64 object formats, and
>   generates source debugging information in STABS, DWARF 2, and CodeView
>   8 formats.